# Who is the guy holding a big axe in "Captain Marvel"? Does he have any connection to anything else?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

I just watched *Captain Marvel* and was confused and didn’t know who this guy with a big axe is. Is there any connections to a movie like *Guardians of the Galaxy*?

[image: A rendering of the character I am asking about]

Comment: The image you have posted appears to be from *Guardians of the Galaxy* not *Captain Marvel*, so surely you already know there's a connection?

Comment: @OrangeDog To be fair to the OP, there's no test or other clues that it's from GoTG (not even one of the main heroes). You'd only know if you've seen the film.

Comment: @OrangeDog, Dammit, I meant "text".

Comment: @Darren yes, but there should be wherever they got the picture from. I'm not even sure how you'd find such an image if you didn't know who the "blue guy with an axe in Captain Marvel" was.

Comment: @OrangeDog this question is now the second result for that search term. :)

Comment: I'm so confused why in the world was this on hermeneutics.stackexchange?

Comment: that's a hammer, not an axe

Comment: His connection to GotG isn't made obvious in Captain Marvel, but he is addressed by name multiple times.

Comment: @Darren the only hint in the picture that its from GotG are the little ships in the background. They look like the ships from Xandar

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes. Hence my point that it would only be obvious if you’ve seen GoTG.

Comment: [Doesn't know who a character is from a film but has the ability to find their image on the internet and still asks who they are] Hmmmmm....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect this is going to be deemed as off-topic. However, it's *Ronan the Accuser*, and yes, he's the big bad from *Guardians of the Galaxy*.

Comment: minus the power stone, of course, during Captain Marvel and a little less fundamentalist.

Comment: **Big** bad? more like **meh** bad